# Botão com formato diferente com CSS

Tags: html5, css3

Precisava fazer um botão com `css` mais ele tem um formato diferente.

É possível fazer um botão assim somente com `css`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Kirito eu te indico fazer com linear-gradiente, assim o canto fica transparente e mesmo o fundo sento uma imagem vc consegue ver sem problemas.

```css
body {
    background-image: url(http://unsplash.it/300/300);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.canto {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, black 90%, transparent 90%);
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    color: peachpuff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="canto">Meu BTN</div>
```

Comment: Uhhhh, esse é um snippet de exemplo ou isso é um erro?

Comment: @I_like_trains acho que eh um erro do snippet pois todos dar o com o mesmo problema, pelo menos aqui pra mim....

Comment: Sim, já reparei em várias respostas, mas boa resposta

Comment: @I_like_trains obrigado :D

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível. Você pode fazer assim:

```
div {
    height: 50px;
    background: #0099d9;
    position: relative;
    width:300px;
}

div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    border-top: 20px solid white;
    border-left: 20px solid #0099d9;
    width: 0;
}
```